# How do you implement text color on taxonomy terms

Tags: taxonomy-terms, forms, theming

I want to implement different font colors on my taxonomy terms. I have installed and configured my color module version 7.x-1.0-rc1 but still I can't find any result.

Comment: How many taxonomy terms do you expect? and are you planing for automated colors rather than fixed colors for each term?

Comment: I actually want a fixed color for each item. I have 2 terms, for my "status" taxonomy vocabulary

Comment: Why don't you use css then. Each term would have its own class you can use that to set a color.

Comment: Sound simplier.How can I achieve that? what css page will I edit and where will I declare the classes on each taxonomy term?

Comment: If you look at the generated html code you would see the classes for the terms. You can use that classes to define the color in the css of your theme.

Comment: Where can I find the generated html code?

Comment: you can look at the source of the html.

Answer (score 4):

Here are steps you need:

1. Install [jQuery Colorpicker](https://drupal.org/project/jquery_colorpicker) module.
2. In the vocabulary for terms for which you want to add colours, add a jquery color picker field.
3. So when you create each term, you also select a colour for it while creating. in this way each taxonomy term will have a colour.
4. now in the taxonomy term preprocess template, write something like this to grab the color and pass it as variable.

   ```
   function themename_preprocess_taxonomy_term(&$vars) {
     $colour_code = $vars['taxonomy_term']->field_yourcolorfieldname['und'][0]['value'];
     $vars['colour_code'] = $colour_code;
   }
   ```

Then copy the taxonomy-term.tpl.php to your theme folder, and you will be having $colour_code variable giving you the colour code of the term. you it to provide an inline css.

Remember, if overriding taxonomy term template is not what you need, or you want to have it elsewhere, whenever you get $term object, you can get the colour code through `$term->field_yourcolourfieldname['und'][0]['value'].`

Comment: this is cool and clean!

Comment: Where can I find this "now in the taxonomy term preprocess template"

Comment: copy /modules/taxonomy/taxonomy-term.tpl.php to you theme. Them modify the copied taxonomy-term.tpl.php file

Comment: And for your preprocess funciton, you need to implement the themename_preprocess_taxonomy_term(&$vars) function i wrote in your theme's template.php file. Ofcourse replace 'themename' with the name of your theme.

Comment: I dont have a taxonomy folder in my modules folder

Comment: remember the location is not sites/all/modules but the modules folder in your root installation - '/modules'. this is where core modules are there.

Comment: Thanks. I'm used to using the sites/all/modules directory in accessing files. The way I understand this is, it overrides the existing taxonomy-term.tpl.php file of the taxonomy folder?

Comment: Do I have to paste it in themes/themename/templates?
After I have copied the taxonomy-term.tpl.php to your theme folder do I need to do something else?

Comment: I think this doesn't work for me. Any other questions?